# Couchbase Secondary index on filter

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am working with Couchbase 6.0. I know that we can create Secondary index on a filter.

So I have created a index like

```
CREATE INDEX idx_zipcode
       ON userbucket(zipcode)
       WHERE status = "active";
```

I have a question here:

Can I create an index on a filter clause if field is dynamic.

Something like this

```
CREATE INDEX idx_zipcode
       ON userbucket(zipcode)
       WHERE status = ? ;
```

Second question is,

which one is better in terms of performance:

```
Single index on 2 fields

CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON userbucket('fname','lname')
```

or

Separate Index on each field

```
CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON userbucket('fname')
CREATE INDEX idx_2 ON userbucket('lname')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No we can not create the index with the dynamic clause mentioned accepting a bind variable.

However, when it is sure that the status and zipcode are part of predicates and dynamic in nature the index like below would be handy.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_zipcode_status  ON userbucket(zipcode, status);
```

Refer [Couchbase Index Creation Blog - right performance](https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/).

Regarding the second query the same principle applies as

> Index selection for a query solely depends on the filters in the WHERE
>   clause of your query

Secondary Composite index is also okay when you have both or leading columns in your query.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON userbucket('fname','lname')
```

The above index would be exploited by queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM userbucket WHERE fname= 'fnam' AND lname= 'lnam';
```

Comment: thanks @Rizwan to clarify on first question. However, regarding second question i want to know that which one will be fast.

Comment: which is faster  i.e having one index on 2 fields or having separate index on each field.

Comment: @lokendralovely this could be a biased answer for the performance optimal. As it serve two different dictionaries maintain for that Index - Composite (col a, col b) <- serves for larger data. But specific index on a column would also result higher throughput if you have only that column in your where condition.